# How to do many-to-many entries with unique constraints efficiently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can not figure this out. I am trying to learn sqlalchemy and I have searched a lot on stack overflow. I need to get this script to work. There is an issue with genres with I can't figure out.

the main issue is that previously added genre isn’t allowed to be added or updated again to a different movie.

**E4:** How do I redefine my model to allow sqlalchemy to handle unique constraint and still be able to insert new title, link it to a genre and add new genre if it does not exist to genres table?

```
from sqlalchemy import exc, orm
from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import pandas as pd


class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:?charset=utf8'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_ECHO = False
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = 'False'
    FLASK_ENV = 'test'
    DEBUG = True


db = SQLAlchemy()
conf = Config()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(conf)
    db.init_app(app)

    return app


association_table = db.Table('association',
                             db.Column('movies_id', db.Integer,
                                       db.ForeignKey('movies.id')),
                             db.Column('genres_id', db.Integer,
                                       db.ForeignKey('genres.id'))
                             )


class Rating(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ratings'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("movies.id"), primary_key=True)
    rating = db.Column(db.String(4),
                       index=True, nullable=False)
    movie = db.relationship("Movie", back_populates="rating")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.rating)


class Movie(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    director = db.Column(db.String(30), primary_key=False,
                         unique=False, nullable=False)
    added = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    rating = db.relationship("Rating", uselist=False, back_populates="movie")
    genres = db.relationship(
        "Genre", secondary=association_table, backref=db.backref('movies'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)


class Genre(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'genres'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True,
                         unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.category)


def set_commit(set_title, set_director, set_rating, set_genre):
    desired_title = set_title
    desired_director = set_director
    desired_rating = set_rating
    desired_genre = set_genre
    msg = f'status:{desired_title}:{desired_director}:{desired_rating}:{desired_genre}:'

    existing_title = Movie.query.filter_by(title=desired_title).first()
    existing_genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category=desired_genre).first()
    if not existing_title:
        movie = Movie(title=desired_title.lower(),
                  director=desired_director.lower(), added=datetime.today())
        rating = Rating(rating=desired_rating, movie=movie)
        genre = Genre(category=desired_genre.lower())
        db.session.add_all([movie, rating])
        msg += 'added all:'
        if not existing_genre:
            db.session.add(genre)
            msg += 'added:'
        if existing_genre not in movie.genres:
            movie.genres.append(genre)
            msg += f'appended:{genre}:{movie.genres}:'
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            msg += 'committed:'
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"commit | {e}")
            db.session.rollback()
            msg += 'rolled back:'
    return msg


def get_entries():
    query = (
        db.session
        .query(
            Rating.rating,
            Movie.title,
            Movie.director,
            Movie.added,
            db.func.GROUP_CONCAT(Genre.category, ", ").label("genres")
        )
        .select_from(Movie)
        .where(Rating.id == Movie.id)
        .join(Genre, Movie.genres)
        .group_by(
            Rating.rating,
            Movie.title,
            Movie.director,
        )
        .limit(10)
    )
    items = pd.read_sql_query(query.statement, db.engine)
    return items


app = create_app()
context = app.app_context()
context.push()
db.create_all()

print(set_commit("t1", "james cameron", 5.0, "horror"))
print(set_commit("t1", "james cameron", 5.0, "comedy"))
print(set_commit("t2", "james cameron", 5.0, "action"))
print(set_commit("t3", "JOnatHan Mostow", 5.0, "aCtion"))
print(set_commit("t4", "Joseph McGinty Nichol", 5.0, "drama"))
print(set_commit("t5", "Jonathan Mostow", 5.0, "drama"))
print(set_commit("t6", "foo bar", 5.0, "biography"))
print(set_commit("t7", "Jonathan Mostow", 5.0, "documentary"))
print(set_commit("t8", "Jonathan Mostow", 5.0, "drama"))
print(set_commit("t9", "Jonathan Mostow", 5.0, "drama"))
print(set_commit("t10", "Jonathan Mostow", 5.0, "biography"))
print(set_commit("t11", "Jonathan Mostow", 4.9, "documentary"))
print(set_commit("t4", "John Cameron", 5.0, "biography"))
print(set_commit("t5", "Jonathan Mostow", 5.0, "horror"))

print(get_entries())
context.pop()
```

My stack trace. It appears that the there is an issue with the genre. So I don't know how to handle unique constraints and multiple entries.

```
status:t1:james cameron:5.0:horror:added all:added:appended:horror:[horror]:committed:
status:t1:james cameron:5.0:comedy:
status:t2:james cameron:5.0:action:added all:added:appended:action:[action]:committed:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('action',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t3:JOnatHan Mostow:5.0:aCtion:added all:added:appended:action:[action]:rolled back:
status:t4:Joseph McGinty Nichol:5.0:drama:added all:added:appended:drama:[drama]:committed:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('drama',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t5:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:drama:added all:appended:drama:[drama]:rolled back:
status:t6:foo bar:5.0:biography:added all:added:appended:biography:[biography]:committed:
status:t7:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:documentary:added all:added:appended:documentary:[documentary]:committed:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('drama',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t8:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:drama:added all:appended:drama:[drama]:rolled back:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('drama',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t9:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:drama:added all:appended:drama:[drama]:rolled back:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('biography',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t10:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:biography:added all:appended:biography:[biography]:rolled back:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('documentary',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t11:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:documentary:added all:appended:documentary:[documentary]:rolled back:
status:t4:John Cameron:5.0:biography:
commit | (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: genres.category
[SQL: INSERT INTO genres (category) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: ('horror',)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
status:t5:Jonathan Mostow:5.0:horror:added all:appended:horror:[horror]:rolled back:
  rating title               director       added       genres
0    5.0    t1          james cameron  2021-05-07       horror
1    5.0    t2          james cameron  2021-05-07       action
2    5.0    t4  joseph mcginty nichol  2021-05-07        drama
3    5.0    t6                foo bar  2021-05-07    biography
4    5.0    t7        jonathan mostow  2021-05-07  documentary
```

How can I get this to work?

E3:

I tried with this suggestion

```
def set_commit(set_title, set_director, set_rating, set_genre):
    desired_title = set_title.lower()
    desired_director = set_director.lower()
    desired_rating = set_rating
    desired_genre = set_genre.lower()
    msg = f'status:{desired_title}:{desired_director}:{desired_rating}:{desired_genre}:'

    existing_title = Movie.query.filter_by(title=desired_title).first()
    existing_genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category=desired_genre).first()
    if not existing_title:
        movie = Movie(title=desired_title,
                      director=desired_director, added=datetime.today())
        rating = Rating(rating=desired_rating, movie=movie)
        genre = Genre(category=desired_genre)
        db.session.add_all([movie, rating])
        msg += 'added all:'
        if not existing_genre:
            db.session.add(genre)
            movie.genres.append(genre)
            msg += 'added:'
        if existing_genre not in movie.genres:
            movie.genres.append(genre)
            msg += f'appended:{genre}:{movie.genres}:'
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            msg += 'committed:'
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"commit | {e}")
            db.session.rollback()
            msg += 'rolled back:'
    return msg
```

Part of its stacktrace:

```
  rating title               director       added                    genres
0    5.0    t1          james cameron  2021-05-08            horror, horror
1    5.0    t2          james cameron  2021-05-08            action, action
2    5.0    t4  joseph mcginty nichol  2021-05-08              drama, drama
3    5.0    t6                foo bar  2021-05-08      biography, biography
4    5.0    t7        jonathan mostow  2021-05-08  documentary, documentary
```

I thought SQLAlchemy could handle this by itself. Is there a more SQLAlchemy intuitive way of rewriting this code?

Comment: Well, you are passing a list (`['action', 'postapocalyptic']`) where a string value is expected for `genres.category = ?` clause. Basically, your `set_commit()` method does not support multiple genres, so you should implement handling the case when you pass a list of genres.

Comment: Yes, but even if i remove that alternative it breaks. That’s more the issue I can’t fix.

Comment: But in this case the error must be different. The error code you posted is clearly about this type mistmatch

Comment: No, actually the error code includes both the issue with list and the issue with the duplicate genre. I will clean it up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you're querying your database for a `Genre`:

```
existing_genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category=desired_genre).first()
```

In your code `desired_genre` is supplied a string (which will work) and in your last example:

```
set_commit("t4", "Joseph McGinty Nichol", 5.0, ["action", "postapocalyptic"])
```

You supply it a list, which doesn't work, this doesn't make sense:

```
existing_genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category=["action", "postapocalyptic"]).first()
```

So you need code to check if it's a list or a string-- if it's a list, to iterate through it and fire a query to check for each entry.

#### After Question Update

So the problem is-- if you have an existing genre ('action') in the
database, providing another:

```
print(set_commit("t3", "JOnatHan Mostow", 5.0, "aCtion"))
```

call, causes a unique error, in this case `action` already exists in the database, but we're providing `aCtion` as the
'new' entry.  The error is telling us that you're trying to add another `action` genre, so my immediate thought
is we're creating a bug to do with the `lower()` and adding entries. So lets walk through:

```
existing_genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category=desired_genre).first()
```

At this point, I expect `None` back-- `desired_genre` is `aCtion` but we know that only `action` exists--
so nothing is returned. I'd suggest:

```
existing_genre = Genre.query.filter_by(category=desired_genre.lower()).first()
```

Since you know you want to normalize to lower-case always.  The next problem is with:

```
if not existing_genre:
    db.session.add(genre)
    msg += 'added:'
if existing_genre not in movie.genres:
    movie.genres.append(genre)
    msg += f'appended:{genre}:{movie.genres}:'
```

If we legit created a new genre-- let's say `noir`, the first `if` would be `false` so we create the
entry, which makes sense-- but even when we create the entry, the second `if` would also be false because
`existing_genre` doesn't change.  There's a few ways to handle that, but the simple way is:

```
if not existing_genre:
    db.session.add(genre)
    movie.genres.append(genre)
    msg += 'added:'
if existing_genre not in movie.genres:
    movie.genres.append(genre)
    msg += f'appended:{genre}:{movie.genres}:'
```

If we need to add a genre, then it *cannot* already be assigned to a movie-- so lets just assign it then
and there, and we'll leave the other check for when an existing genre is present.

Comment: I have updated my post. I removed the list but kept the core issue of duplicates. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I believe I updated the as you suggested but this only caused duplicate genres to be added.

Comment: I have tried to get this to work bit I have not been able to. Can you provide a working implementation?